# 1d conv error - input and filter sizes need to be the same?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a 1d CNN on eeg signals, and I am getting an error which says

> ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 492 and 1
>     From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'MaxPool/input' (op: 'Pack') with > input shapes: [?,492,64], [50,1,64].

[?, 492, 64] (batchsize, in_width, channels) I believe this is the output tensor for the 1st Conv1d layer

[50, 1, 64] (filter_width, in_channels, out_channels) is the shape of the 1st Conv1d weight.

Why would 492 and 1 have to be equal?  I am not understanding the error which is stopping me from finding the issue.  Its my 1st week with tensor flow and any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.  Code that is causing the error below.

```
# Convolutional Layer 1s
filter_size_1s = 50
num_filters_1s = 64
stride_1s = 6
# Convolutional Layer 2s , 3s , 4s
filter_size_s = 8
num_filters_s = 128
stride_s = 1

#weights and biases
# filter tensor of shape [filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]
W_1s = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([50, 1, 64], stddev=0.1))  
B_1s = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, tf.float32, [64]))
W_2s = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([8, 64, 128], stddev=0.1))  
B_2s = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, tf.float32, [128]))
W_3s = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([8, 128, 128], stddev=0.1)) 
B_3s = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, tf.float32, [128]))
W_4s = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([8, 128, 128], stddev=0.1))  
B_4s = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, tf.float32, [128]))


def CNN_small(input, phase_test, iteration):

    conv1s = new_conv_layer(input, W_1s, B_1s, stride_1s, phase_test, iteration)
    max_pool1s = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1s, 
                           ksize=[1, pool_size_1s, 1, 1],
                           strides=[1, pool_stride_1s, 1, 1], 
                           padding='VALID')

    dropout_s = tf.nn.dropout(max_pool1s, dropout_prob)    
    conv2s = new_conv_layer(dropout_s, W_2s, B_2s, stride_s, phase_test, iteration)    
    conv3s = new_conv_layer(conv2s, W_3s, B_3s, stride_s, phase_test, iteration)    
    conv4s = new_conv_layer(conv3s, W_4s, B_4s, stride_s, phase_test, iteration)
    max_pool2s = tf.nn.max_pool(conv4s, 
                           ksize=[1, pool_size_2s, 1, 1],
                           strides=[1, pool_stride_2s, 1, 1], 
                           padding='VALID')
    return max_pool2s

def new_conv_layer(input, weights, bias, stride, phase_test, iteration):

    conv = tf.nn.conv1d(value=input, filters=weights, stride=stride, padding='VALID') + bias
    #bn = batch_norm(conv, biases, phase_test, iteration)    #biases added into batch_norm
    activation = tf.nn.relu(conv)
    return activation, weights

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, stage_length], name='x')
x_stage = tf.reshape(x, [-1, stage_length, num_channels])   #batch, in_width, channels

#And the line which is giving the error
#cnn layer
max_pool2s = CNN_small(x_stage, phase_test, iteration)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `new_conv_layer` function is returning two tensors, and you're trying to use it as if it only returns one. If you don't use the weights after the layer, just change the `return` statement to

```
return activation
```

You may also find the [`tf.layers`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers) API cleaner.

Comment: Thanks!  that was the problem.  Appreciate your help.